# Laravel max() in join

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to avoid using a subquery in my query.

Is there a way to do the following (I know the below doesn't work):

```
...
->leftJoin('sales', function($j) {
            $j->on('sales.customer_id', '=', 'c.id')->max('sale_date');
        })
...
```

Comment: Maybe using `DB::raw` inside your `on` https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects might help

Comment: It could be helpful if you could show the SQL query you are trying to create in SQL.